# How can I remotely shutdown a Raspberry PI from my network via a Web Interface?

Tags: php, web

I am wondering how I could possibly input the values for option (e.g -r), time (e.g now) and message (e.g Shutting down), I have tried:

```
system("shutdown " . $option . "-t " . $time . " " . $message);
```

and that didn't work? (I am doing it via PHP, also.)

This is the code that I have so far in shutdown.php:

```
<?php 
$option = $_POST['option'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$message = $_POST['message];
?>
```

I am using Apache 2 by the way.

Comment: The Pi is a general Linux box and is nothing special in this regard.  Why not just have a shutdown script on the Pi (such as sudo shutdown -hP now) and just invoke the script?

Comment: I'm not exactly a Linux genius :P , you might have to explain how I would go about doing such a thing

Comment: Login to the Pi (user pi presumably).  Enter nano off.  Add two lines, the first with **#!/bin/bash**, the second with **sudo shutdown -hP now**.  Make it executable, **chmod +x off**.  In your PHP use system("/home/pi/off");

Comment: I've just executed it from my Mac on the same network and it's not shutting down?

Comment: There I can't help.  I don't have an environment set-up to issue web commands to my Pi.  Apache/PHP should log errors on the Pi somewhere.

Comment: Okay - I will try and find the error_log file if there is one

Comment: @joan and connor: Joan's solution doesn't work because Apache (user www-data) doesn't have sudo rights, which is required by the shutdown command. Your options are to either give www-data sudo rights (DO NOT DO THIS!) or give it rights to the shutdown executable through group policy.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Alternatively, and in my view just as safe, is to give www-data sudo privileges over the single script.

Comment: @joan: I've never heard of such a thing... Sounds like a good idea to me, though, measures would have to be taken to ensure that the script doesn't change.

Comment: @Jacobm001 If you do a man sudoers and search for dgb there are some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Not without additional [hardware](https://www.pi-supply.com/product/pi-supply-raspberry-pi-power-switch/).

There is no "off"-switch on the pi - when it's plugged in, it is powered.

You can put it in a runlevel that makes it disappear from the net, and you can reboot it.

The reason your php-script doesn't work, however, is probably that the user it is executing as does not have the rights to run the `shutdown`-command. This should show up in the `/var/log/syslog`-file.

Comment: I mean shutdown - and how would I give the user the correct permissions?

Comment: That is why joan suggested `sudo shutdown...`. So make sure the respective user has the right to `sudo` see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo There should be a special user that runs apache/php.